# EntityFramework Update with one roundtrip to the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a table as follow:

**Contacts:**

```
| Id | Name  | Age |
|----|-------|-----|
| 1  | amir  | 35  |
| 2  | steve | 29  |
```

And also have POCO entities (detached entity) as follow:

```html
var contacts = new [] {
                        Contact {Id = 1, Age = 34},
                        Contact {Id = 2, Age = 25}
                       };
```

and then:

```html
using (var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    ctx.Contacts.Update(contacts);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

What is the best practice to update table rows mentioned at the first with one round-trip database via entity-framework (code first)? 
**Note:** I want to update only **Age** column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF Core supports batching and if you set its batch size to 1, you will get the same result as EF 6.x

```
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
   @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Demo.Batching;Trusted_Connection=True;",
   options => options.MaxBatchSize(1)
);
```

Which means you should start using the EF Core instead of EF 6.x, if you want less round trips to the db for insert/update/delete, or you should use 3dr party libraries which support `BulkUpdate` such as https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus

Comment: `ctx.Contacts.Where(x => x.Id == 1).Update(x => new Contact  { Age = 34});ctx.Contacts.Where(x => x.Id == 2).Update(x => new Contact { Age = 25}); ctx.SaveChanges();` is it correct with EF-Plus?

Comment: Its update method has a batchsize parameter `.Update(x => ..., update => { update.BatchDelayInterval = 50;  update.BatchSize = 5; })`. It's useful for range updates.